# 多重ループを高速化する方法

Tags: python, python3

これまで自分なりに色々と高速化を試行錯誤した結果がこちらなのですが、恥ずかしながらまだまだ改善の余地はあると思っております。
こちらを更に高速化する方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

ご参考として、実際私が実行しているループ文はab,cde,,,が計17個あり、変数のrangeのほとんどが3ですので約4000万通りほど実行しております。

```py
for ab in range(3):
    for cde in range(2):
        for fg in range(3):
            for hi in range(3):
                Return=np.r_[Return_AB[ab], #Return_ABの中身は(1,41)のnp.array
                             Return_CDE[cde], #Return_CDEの中身は(1,41)のnp.array
                             Return_FG[fg], #Return_FGの中身は(1,41)のnp.array
                             Return_HI[hi]] #Return_HIの中身は(1,41)のnp.array
                Return_total = np.sum(Return, axis=0)
                Return_dif = Return_total-BM #BMは(1,41)のデータフレーム
                Num0 = max(Num0_AB[ab],Num0_CDE[cde],Num0_FG[fg],Num0_HI[hi]) #4~8の値
                Win_Pro = (Return_dif.iloc[:,Num0:] > 0).sum(axis=1) / (Number_Date-Num0)
                if Win_Pro.item() < 1:
                    continue
                Cum_return = np.prod(Return_dif.iloc[:,Num0:]+1, axis=1)-1
                if Cum_return.item() < 0.1:
                    continue
                TE = Return_dif.iloc[:,Num0:].std(axis=1)
                Result.append([Win_Pro.item(),Cum_return.item(),TE.item(),Num0,ab,cde,fg,hi])
```

Comment: 繰り返し回数が多い訳でもないので、for文の中身を高速化するのが良さそうです。

Comment: `multiprocessing` などを使って並行処理かな、と思ったんですが、 `Return` をsumしているので無理そうですね……。

Comment: 取得したデータをどのように利用するのでしょうか？

Comment: 4000万通りの処理はそれぞれ独立なので、用途・環境によっては、分散処理する方法もありそうです。例えば、4000万個のタスクをqueueに突っ込んで、複数のマシンの複数のワーカーからそれを読んで処理し、処理結果をデータベースに書き込むようなやり方です。

Comment: このループ文で得られる結果は約200万通りとなります。その200万通りののちの使い道ですが、それぞれの列の数値（例えば`ab=1,cde=0,,,`）を別のnp.arrayの呼び込みに使ってます。`Memb_AB=Flag_AB[Result’AB’][i]]`こういったものを17個全て抽出に使ってます。もう少し厳密に描くと、`Memb_=[] for i in range(len(Result)): Memb_AB=Flag_AB[Result’AB’][i]] Memb_CDE=Flag_CDE[Result’CDE’][i]],,, Memb_.append([Memb_AB,Memb_CDE,,,,`こういった形で利用しています。`Flag_AB`の中身はnp.arrayです。

Answer (score 4):

この質問のケーズでは、繰り返しをやめてNumpyやPandasのベクトル計算を使うのは必要なメモリーが莫大になるで、繰り返し処理はそのままにして、`Numba`か`Cython`を使って高速化するのがいいと思われます。

`Numba`は簡単に使えるのでとりあえず`Numba`を試してみてはどうですか。

```
import numba

@numba.jit
def calc():
    NMAX = 10000000 #オーバフローしない数値にしておく
    Win_Pro = np.zeros(NMAX) 
    Cum_return = np.zeros(NMAX) 
    TE = np.zeros(NMAX)
    N = np.zeros(NMAX, dtype=int)
    A = np.zeros((4, NMAX), dtype=int)

    int n = 0
    for ab in range(3):
        for cde in range(2):
            for fg in range(3):
                for hi in range(3):
                    Return_total = Return_AB[ab] + #Return_ABの中身は(41)のnp.array
                                 Return_CDE[cde] + #Return_CDEの中身は(41)のnp.array
                                 Return_FG[fg] + #Return_FGの中身は(41)のnp.array
                                 Return_HI[hi] #Return_HIの中身は(41)のnp.array
                    Return_dif = Return_total-BM #BMは(41)のnp.arrayに変換しておく。PandasのDataFrameとSeriesは。df.valuesでnp.arrayに変換できる
                    Num0 = max(Num0_AB[ab],Num0_CDE[cde],Num0_FG[fg],Num0_HI[hi]) #4~8の値
                    Win_Pro[n] = (Return_dif.iloc[:,Num0:] > 0).sum() / (Number_Date-Num0)
                    if Win_Pro[n] < 1:
                        continue
                    Cum_return[n] = np.prod(Return_dif.iloc[:,Num0:]+1) - 1
                    if Cum_return[n] < 0.1:
                        continue
                    TE[n] = Return_dif.iloc[:,Num0:].std()
                    N[n] = Num0
                    A[n] = np.array([ab, cde, fg, hi]) 
                    n += 1

    return Win_Pro[:n], Cum_return[:n],TE[:n], N[:n], A[:n,:]
```

`Return=np.r_`で`ndarray`を結合していますが、それを省略して直接加算した方が速いと思います。
また、Resultはリストのリストになっていますが、リストのリストは処理が遅いので`ndarray`に変更してみました。`pd.concat`を使ってPandasのDataFrameにしておくとその後の利用に便利です。

`Numba`を使っても遅い場合には、`Cython`が使えます。`Cython`の利用については、次の公式マニュアルが参考になると思います。

・Cython [Working with NumPy](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html)
・Pandas [Enhancing Performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html)

`Cython`の場合もそれほど難しいことはないですが、変数の型宣言に手間がかかります。例えば、Jupyter Notebookを使うのであれば、まず Cythonのマジック関数をインポートして

```
%load ext Cython
```

次のようなコードでとりあえず動きます。

```
%%cython
def calc(Return_AB, Return_CDE, Return_FG, ,Num0_AB, Num0_CDE, Num0_FG, Num0_HI, BM):
# 以下略
```

あとは、変数に型宣言をしていくと高速に処理できるようになります。

Comment: この場合、`2^1*3^3=54`通りを実行していると思うのですが、その54通りを収納するのにリストのリストだと処理が遅くなってしまうとのことですが、`pd.concat`を利用してデータフレームとして結果を保存する場合、どういったコードを書けばよろしいのでしょうか。`def`をこれまで使ったことがなく初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが宜しくお願いします。

Comment: def は単なる関数定義であり、Yasuhiro さんは、ここで定義した calc を loop の中で使う意図で、loop 内の処理だけを取り出して解説されているのだと思います。concat を使わなくても、 result を DataFrame() で初期化しておいて、calc の返り値を append していけば十分そうです。

Comment: `import numba`の後に`B=pd.DataFrame()`という風に空のデータフレーム`B`を定義し、`def`文の最後に`return B.append(Win_Pro[:n], Cum_return[:n],TE[:n], N[:n], A[:n,:] )`としたのですが`B`は空のままです。これは何がいけなかったのでしょうか。

Comment: 自分の書いたコードはチェックできていないのでミスがあるかもしれません。人間はよくミスをするので、デバッガーを使ってどこまで計算ができているかチェックをしてみてください。